# How to assign a variable in a Swift case statement

Tags: swift

This works but seems inefficient:

```
switch var1 {
case 1:
    string1 = "hello"
case 2:
    string1 = "there"
default:
    string1 = "world"
}
```

but

```
string1 = switch var1 { ...
```

throws an error. Is there a more efficient way to write the switch/case so that the assigned variable isn't listed redundantly in each line?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See also https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/commonly_proposed.md: There are currently no plans to make `switch` an expression.

Comment: @MartinR "These are conceptually interesting things to support, but many of the problems solved by making these into expressions are already solved in Swift in other ways" as dfri and Tom Harrington elegantly demonstrated.

Comment: @Dribbler such a shame.. I miss you Kotlin!

Comment: I find this quite elegant in functional languages like F# or Elixir. However being able to do `let bla: String` without assigning something the compiler forces that every possible path assigns something.

Comment: @DepartamentoB Wow, awesome. I had no idea these languages existed. And that such a language with fault tolerance for embedded systems exists, I am dying to poke around in it. THANKS MUCHO 

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could put your `switch` block in a function that returns a `String` object, and assign the return of this function to your variable `string1`:

```
func foo(var1: Int) -> String {
    switch var1 {
    case 1:
        return "hello"
    case 2:
        return "there"
    default:
        return "world"
    }
}

/* Example */
var var1 : Int = 1
var string1 : String = foo(var1) // "hello"
var1 = 2
string1 = foo(var1)              // "there"
var1 = 5000
string1 = foo(var1)              // "world"
```

Alternatively let `string1` be a computed property (e.g. in some class), depending in the value of say `var1`, and place the `switch` block in the getter of this property. In a playground:

```
var var1 : Int
var string1 : String {
    switch var1 {
    case 1:
        return "hello"
    case 2:
        return "there"
    default:
        return "world"
    }
}

/* Example */
var1 = 1
print(string1) // hello
var1 = 2
print(string1) // there
var1 = 100
print(string1) // world
```

If used in a class, just skip the Example block above.

Answer (score 130):

Put the `switch` in an anonymous closure, if you'll only use that code in one place.

```
string1 = {
    switch var1 {
    case 1:
        return "hello"
    case 2:
        return "there"
    default:
        return "hello"
    }
}()
```

Answer (score 6):

#### [**Swift v5.9**](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0380-if-switch-expressions.md)

Now you can **directly** assign the value from the `switch/case` expression like:

```
let result = switch range {
    case 0...30: "Low"
    case 31...50: "Medium"
    case 51...80: "Hight"
    default: "Other"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch (and if) expressions were added to Swift 5.9, shipping with Xcode 15.

Example from [Swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/controlflow/#Switch):

```swift
let anotherCharacter: Character = "a"
let message = switch anotherCharacter {
case "a":
    "The first letter of the Latin alphabet"
case "z":
    "The last letter of the Latin alphabet"
default:
    "Some other character"
}


print(message)
// Prints "The first letter of the Latin alphabet"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary instead of a `switch` statement, which is more flexible as it allows you to add new values with little overhead:

```swift
let map = [1: "hello", 2: "there"]
value = map[var1] ?? "world"
```

Or, in a single statement, and by using the `default` subscript:

```swift
let value = [1: "hello", 
             2: "there"][var1, default: "world"]
```

The `default` argument passed to the subscript call works just like the `default` clause from the `switch`

Comment: This throws out the ability of the compiler to tell you that your switch statement does not cover all cases.

Comment: Agreed, however using a `default` clause, like in the code the asker posted, has the same pitfall as you mentioned. Also the switch seems to be on an integer value, and an exhaustive switch for that is a little bit hard to write :)